# how to replicate each element differently use tensorflow dataset API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I create a tensorflow dataset `train_image` which has 10 class A image, and 20 class B image. 
now how can I replicate each class separately?

I want `train_image` to include 100 class A image (10 repeat on each class A image), and 100 class B image (5 repeat on each class B image).

Comment: Please show us some codes you have tried, and what's your expected results, etc. It will help to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use data augmentation by ImageDataGenerator, it will transform the images. The set of transformations includes rotation, zooming, etc which are somehow new data. It depends on how many epochs you run, it will generate as many images depending on steps_per_epoch. These augmented images are not stored in memory, they are generated while run and lost after training.

```
datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
featurewise_center=True,
featurewise_std_normalization=True,
rotation_range=20,
width_shift_range=0.2,
height_shift_range=0.2,
horizontal_flip=True)
```